# How to find each case of matching pattern within a string and return as rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to identify reference numbers contained in strings in a column. The table looks something like this:

```
col1  col2
1     fgREF1234fhjdREF1235hgkjREF1236
2     hREF1237hjdfREF1238djhfhs
```

Need to write an SQL query that identifies the 'REF' followed by the 4 digits and returns each in its own row.

The output should look like this:

```
col1  ref
1     REF1234
1     REF1235
1     REF1236
2     REF1237
2     REF1238
```

I have tried:

```
select
    case when substr(substr(col2, instr(col2, 'REF'), 7), 1, 1) like 'R'
    then substr(col2, instr(col2, 'R'), 7) else null end ref
from table
```

...but this will only identify the first match in the string.

I am using Oracle SQL but ideally the solution would be able to be converted to other SQL variants.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_substr` delimited by `connect by level <= regexp_count(col2,'REF')` ( *the appearance time of the pattern string `REF` within the strings `col2`* )

```
with t(col1,col2) as
(
 select 1,'fgREF1234fhjdREF1235hgkjREF1236' from dual union all
 select 2,'hREF1237hjdfREF1238djhfhs' from dual
)   
select col1,
       regexp_substr(col2,'REF[0-9]+',1,level) as ref
  from t
connect by level <= regexp_count(col2,'REF') 
    and prior col1 = col1
    and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/CVZS38425)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the desired result :-

```
  select x.col1, explode(x.ref) as ref from (
  select col1,split(trim(regexp_replace(col2,'[^REF0-9]',' ')),'    ') as ref
  from inp
```